# Error: An error occured loading the captcha picture, reloading

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to Log in to Ubuntu One (Ubuntu Single sign on) after installation of Ubuntu, and it is not possible. I get the message above all the time. What can I do? (I am Ubuntu novice;)

Comment: Hello. Please expand in your question by adding info about your system and what you have tried so far. Are you otherwise able to connect to the internet?

Comment: Have you created your Ubuntu One account?  if so telling us where may help us to understand your issue (ie. *[this maybe helpful in creating an account](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount) or [here for FAQ](https://login.ubuntu.com/+faq); but you've given few details as to how far you got*)